# Why does google drive api create a File with a null name

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm getting an NullPointerException from **uploadedFile.getName()** in the following code that utilizes the google api. If I change that to a string fileName the code works fine.

```
public static void downloadFile(boolean useDirectDownload, File uploadedFile, java.io.File parentDir)throws IOException {
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new java.io.File(parentDir, uploadedFile.getName()));
    DRIVE.files().get(uploadedFile.getId()).executeMediaAndDownloadTo(out);
}
```

I understand what a null pointer is but not sure why I'm getting one in this case because prior to calling the download file I set the filename in code earlier and the file is uploaded with the name I set.

```
public static File uploadFile(boolean useDirectUpload, String uploadFilePath, String fileType, String fileName) throws IOException {

File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName(fileName);
fileMetadata.setMimeType(fileType);

java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File(uploadFilePath);
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(fileType, filePath);
return DRIVE.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
        .setFields("id")
        .execute();
}
```

The above two sets of code are called by

```
java.io.File parentDir = P.createDirectory("C:\\DIR");         
File uploadedFile = P.uploadFile(true, "C:\\DIR\AA.pdf", "application/pdf", "BB.pdf");
P.downloadFile(true, uploadedFile, parentDir);
```

**For a specific question, why does the File returned by the following statement have null for the name?**

```
return DRIVE.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
            .setFields("id")
            .execute();
```

Maven dependency for drive services:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
    <version>v3-rev40-1.22.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**why does the File returned by the following statement have null for the name?**

Because you haven't requested the file name to be included in the REST response. Change `.setFields("id")` to  `.setFields("id, name")`

Answer (score 2):

You're only getting `id` as part of the partial response when the `create` method is called since its the only one specified in the `setFields` - https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/Drive.Files.Create.html.

Try to add other fields (`name`, and other related fields necessary) and the call should work